# How to Completely Remove an Android Layout from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm building an app in Android Studio and I accidentally created a base `LoginActivity` template but then deleted it because I wanted to make my own. Now, when I try creating another activity with the same name, it tells me "Layout name must be unique."

I could just name it something else but:

1. I don't want to
2. There would still be some sort of duplicate files in my system doing nothing

My goal is to just remove all mentions of `activity_login`, ultimately so I can make a new activity with the same name, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `res->layout->activity_login.xml` and delete it from android studio

Or open project in file explorer, then Go to `app/src/main/res/layout/activity_login.xml` and delete it

If it didn't solve it, Invalidate Caches and restart Android Studio.

Comment: I did. I also removed its items from several other directories and I still get this error. Like I said, I already deleted it

Comment: @EthanShoe updated my answer. you said you removed activity, but it doesn't delete layout file automatically

Comment: The file was already gone from that directory but Invalidating the caches and restarting Android Studio did the trick. Thank you much!

Answer (score 0):

That's happens sometimes.
just go to : `File->Manage IDE Settings -> Restore Default Settings`.
This will solve it for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Empty `res/layout/activity_xxxxx.xml` and invalidate cache didn't work, until I found there's `xxxxx.java` existing in `app\src\main\java\com\example\xxxxx`. After deleting the .java file as well, I found that I'm able to create the Activity file with the same name.

Comment: Just remove the file and it is solved. I had the same problem.